# Trichotomy of rationals

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> In Terence Tao Analysis $1$, I face the problem of proving the trichotomy of rationals.

Definition (to help):

> A rational number $x$ is said to be positive iff we have
>   $x = a/b$ for some positive integers $a$ and $b$. It is said to be negative iff
>   we have $x = −y$ for some positive rational $y$ (i.e., $x = (−a)/b$ for some
>   positive integers $a$ and $b$).

There was a hint that suggested to prove firstly, that at least one of $= 0$, positive, negative is true; and secondly, that at most one of them is true.

**At most one of them**:

*if $x=0 => a=0$ by definition, so $a/b \not> 0$ and $a/b \not< 0$.

*if $x > 0$ and $x < 0 => a/b = n, n >0$ and $a/b = -n, n < 0$. Therefore, $n=-n$ for some $n \in Z => n = 0 => x=0$

Therefore, at most one of the relations can hold true.

**At least one of them**:

$x = \frac{a}{b}$. We know that any $y \in Z$ one of the $y=0, y<0, y>0$ is true. Since $a,b \in Z$ we have the following cases:

$1)$ First case or $y=0.$ If $b = 0$ then the rational number $x$ is not definied by definition (the way I wrote it sounds stupid :) ). If $a=0$ then also by definition we have that $x = 0$.
$2)$ Second case or $y > 0$. If $a>0$ and $b > 0$ then $x = \frac{a}{b}$ by definition $x > 0$.
$3)$ Third case or $y<0$.
$3.1) a>0$ and $b<0$ then $\exists n\in N; a = n$ and $\exists m\in N; b =-m$. By cancelation law and commutativity for integers $ab = nb = bn$; $a(-m) = bn$. Therefore, $x^{-1}=\frac{b}{a} = \frac{(-m)}{n} = -\frac{m}{n}$. Hence, $x^{-1}<0$ by definition.
 At this point we need to show that if $x^{-1} < 0$ then $x<0$. Suppose $x>0 => x^{-1} = \frac{1}{x}=\frac{b}{a} => x^{-1} > 0$ by definition. Therefore, by contrapositive it is true that when $x^{-1} <0; x<0$.
$3.2) a<0$ and $b>0$ $x=\frac{a}{b}$ by the same construction as above, $x=\frac{-n}{m} = -\frac{n}{m}$. So, $x<0$ by definition.
$3.3) a<0$ and $b < 0$ then $\exists n,m \in N; a=-n, b=-m$. Hence, $x=\frac{a}{b} = \frac{-n}{-m}=-\frac{n}{-m}$.
Since $\frac{n}{-m}$, was a negative rational number by $3.1$ we need to show that $(-1)$*negative rational $=$ positive rational.
Let $y=\frac{-c}{d}, z = \frac{-1}{1}$ for some $y \in Q$. $zy=\frac{-1}{1}*\frac{-c}{d}=\frac{(-1)(-c)}{d}$ but since for any $c \in Z$ we have that $(-1)a=-a$ then $(-1)(-c)=c$. Therefore $x = (-1)*\frac{n}{-m}>0$

So at least one of the relations must hold. I basically edited all the second part of the answer. I would like to know if the logic that I am using is correct and if not I would love to get any help. (Note: in the places when I am saying that we know some facts, especially while working with integers, I am referring to the previous chapters of the book, that is definitions and exercises that have been completed already).